# Invalid Link when building with --prod

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3.

I am able to build and run the app without any problems using `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova run ios`.

However, When I build the app with `--prod` flag (`ionic cordova run ios --prod`), I get a white screen after the Splash Screen. I checked the console and found out the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: introduction-slides

IntroductionSlides page is the very first page that I set as the rootPage in app.component.ts.

I checked my IntroductionSlides page and made sure that I have the correct name for the page:

```
@IonicPage({
    name: “introduction-slides”
})
```

I also made sure that I have introduction-slides.module.ts file.

I have been having a real hard time trying to resolve this issue. Please know that it all works fine except when running with --prod flag.

Note: Following are my devDependencies from package.json:

```
“devDependencies”: {
“@angular/cli”: “^1.7.3”,
“@ionic/app-scripts”: “^3.1.9”,
“@types/googlemaps”: “^3.30.7”,
“ionic”: “^3.20.0”,
“typescript”: “^2.3.4”,
“ws”: “3.3.2”
}
```

Comment: did you try `--prod --release` ?

Comment: I only tried --prod. not --release. But I will try it with --release as well.

Comment: @SurajRao I tried --prod --release, no luck.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Just tried a --prod build and I'm getting something similar: `invalid link: n` (I assume the "n" is some minified thing).  Any luck with this?